# Enable toolbar button only during live card display

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

In my Glass application, I display a button on the toolbar. This button shows the on/off state of the camera and lets the user toggle the state.

The problem I am running into is that Glass occasionally moves the focus to the button. As a result, a tap keeps activating the button.

It seems Glass automatically converts toolbar menu items to live cards when top-to-bottom swing is used. This is nice. It gives the users the ability to select a menu item.

I am thinking if I could set the default state of the button to "disabled," it could solve my problem.   However, this also results in disabling the button in the live cards. I would like to enable the button only during live cards.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or, is there a better way to remove focus out of the toolbar? Regards.